# Magento adding actions In orders

Tags: magento, action, status, orders

I'm using Magento Community 1.7. When I go to Sales-->Orders I see all the orders. Currently I can tick certain orders and, using the action dropdown, I can print invoices, cancel, hold etc. I'm wondering if there is anyway that I can add actions like "Requires Refund", "Fraud". The actions wouldn't neccessarily have to do anything just change the status so I can see clearly for later the status of these orders. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In order to add more actions you need to override this method `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid::_prepareMassaction()`.
For each action you add, you will need a method in the controller you send it to.
Take for example the action `Cancel`. It is added to the mass action block like this:

```
$this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
     'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
     'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
));
```

and the corresponding method is `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController::massCancelAction()`